Ignore property with ElasticsearchClientSettings.DefaultMappingFor<>
Migrating from Nest to Elasticsearch V8
Before (using Nest) I had
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(elasticSettings.Uri));
settings
    .ThrowExceptions(elasticSettings.ThrowExceptions)
    .PrettyJson(elasticSettings.PrettyJson)
    .DefaultMappingFor<CorrelationContext>(ms => ms.Ignore(p => p.DgpHeader));

Changed ConnectionSettings to ElasticsearchClientSettings but the Ignore-option on DefaultMappingFor isn't available anymore.
I only find  documentation regarding this for v7 but not for v8
Is it moved to somewhere else?
And if not, how can we achieve the same result?
Update:
After looking further in the documentation I came across the page regarding serialization.
However, I do not have access to the class-code to add the JsonIgnore attribute (class is in other library).

Couldn't find way to do it through settings so ended up creating a new POCO with the exact same name and properties as the original class (obviously without the one property I want to ignore).

8.x versions do not yet integrate all the features of previous versions. You can get more details about this on the official site.
The solutions I have found are using Annotations, and Anonymous Types.
Solution using Annotations
The method ElasticsearchClient.IndexAsync uses Json for indexing. We can use the [JsonIgnore] annotation to ignore such property.
public class MyEntity
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int IgnoreThis { get; set; }

    public int DoNotIgnoreThis { get; set; }
}

var entity = new MyEntity {};
    
await client.IndexAsync(entity);

Solution using Anonymous Types
If using annotations does not work for you, we can use anonymous types:
var entity = new
{
    DoNotIgnoreThis = 3
};

await client.IndexAsync(entity);

